# How to reduce the space between the lines in Jupyter Visual Studio Code Output?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, visual-studio-code

I want to reduce the space between the lines when I print something in Jupyter visual studio code output.

Current output

[image: Screenshot]

I would like an output like Jupyter when I use it in a browser
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible, there is an open PR about it in VC Code Jupyter repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1568

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a new setting is being added to vscode v1.67:

`notebook.outputLineHeight`

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/9a87fe7eaf2bcf29de4f5ec7c02044c410c95c0f

Comment: Wow! That was the solution that I was looking for. Thanks Mark

Comment: P.S. To reproduce the solution I added to settings.json this line in VSCode Insiders:         "notebook.outputLineHeight": 15 The default value was 22. It works like a charm. This new feature it will be great for data science works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if VSCode-Settings has allowed users to customise the line height in Notebooks, but in case it hasn't, you may do so by adjusting the item `line-height` in the file `index.js` in the directory `...\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\notebook-renderers\renderer-out\`

Answer (score 0):

The current name of the setting to use is `notebook.output.lineHeight`. Quoting from defaultSettings.json:

> ```json
> // Line height of the output text within notebook cells.
> //  - When set to 0, editor line height is used.
> //  - Values between 0 and 8 will be used as a multiplier with the font size.
> //  - Values greater than or equal to 8 will be used as effective values.
> "notebook.output.lineHeight": 0,
> ```

For values between 0 and 8, fractional values are accepted and can be used to reduce line spacing.

In older versions of VS Code, the setting was named `notebook.outputLineHeight` (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123149).

Note that in outputs with MathJax, the spacing may be styled differently. See [Jupyter notebook markdown output puts extra vertical padding on lines with inline MathJax expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71337623/11107541).