# Jupyter notebook markdown output puts extra vertical padding on lines with inline MathJax expressions

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, mathjax

Inline MathJax in the Markdown cells of my Jupyter Notebook often (especially when super/subscripts are involved) will cause the rendered line to have as much vertical space as a paragraph break despite no such input.

Here is the rendered version showing what appear to be multiple paragraph breaks:

[image]

And the input, which shows a single paragraph break (though wrapped on SO) right before "It":

```markdown
The solutions the to polynomial $x^d = 1$ are then the powers of *a*, and there are only *d* unique powers of *a* in $Z/(P))^{\times}$ - synergistically, since a polynomial of degree *d* under a multiplicative group has at most *d* roots (or equivalently, solutions, in this case), then all *d* powers of *a*, or the subgroup *A* represent the *only* possible solutions to the polynomial.

It is possible that an element of the subgroup generated by *a* contains elements with orders less than *d* (but never greater than).
```

This completely breaks the flow, looks ugly, and nullifies intended paragraph spacing. Even worse, it seems to be creating space which isn't even required for the expression. Is there a way to achieve a consistent vertical line padding throughout my cell/notebook? I don't remember this always being a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this snippet of the `custom.css` file located at `~/.jupyter/custom` to remove MathJax expressions taking over the line height in your Markdown cells. For me this was located at line 3201.

```css
.MathJax_Display,
.MathJax {
 border: 0 !important;
 font-size: 100% !important;
 text-align: center !important;
 margin: 0em !important;
 //line-height: 2.25 !important; // // // // COMMENT OUT THIS LINE // // // //
```

I'm sure this prevents some very ugly clipping that *can* happen when vertically expansive MathJax expressions are used inline, but I would rather deal with those issues as they arise than constantly having inconsistent and unintended line breaks mid sentence.